# How do I access Registry from C# for a proxy?

Tags: c#, proxy, registry

So I've previously asked this question:

> How do I point a socket to the proxy ip/port using the winforms webbrowser control? The
> standard web browser that comes with Visual C#.NET.
>
> Please help in Visual C#.NET.

I got a response telling me that "WebBrowser is just an interface over IE. To set the IE proxy settings, you can hack the registry!"

He told me to add the following code:

```
    string key = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
    string serverName = "";//your proxy server name;
    string port = ""; //your proxy port;
    string proxy = serverName + ":" + port;

    RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key, true);
    RegKey.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxy);
    RegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
```

Of course, this might be added to something like a button clicked event, and I would need to add in the proxy and port.

The problem is that RegistryKey could not be found because I'm either missing a using directive or an assembly reference, and Registry does not exist in the current context.

I'm assuming I'm missing a using directive for both of those, but I don't know.

How do I fix this problem in Visual C#.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented in the previous question.

```
 using Microsoft.Win32;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=VS.80).aspx